# Using the C# Lambda Operator

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, ffmpeg

I am trying to understand how the lambda operator in C# is used when the given parameters are formatted in ( ), like so:

```
_backgroundVideoWorker.DoWork += (s, e) => 
       { 
           outputFile = _videoEditor.JoinVideo(selectedConfiguration, videoFiles); 
       };
```

My main goal from asking this question is to understand how the different operators are being used with the lambda, `+= (s, e) =>`.

For reference, this code excerpt is taken from an application that is joining two video files together by using the FFMPEG utility.

Comment: `s` and `e` represent the `object sender` and `DoWorkEventArgs e` parameters which are passed to the [`DoWork` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BackgroudWorker.DoWork](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork(v=vs.110).aspx) is an event with a delegate type of [DoWorkEventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx), which has the signature:

```
public delegate void DoWorkEventHandler(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

which means that DoWork would be a function that receives two parameters, of type `object` and `DoWorkEventArgs`, respectively.

The event handler has to follow the same signature as the event's delegate, therefore, when you speficy `(s, e) => { /*..*/ }` as the event handler, the compiler will assume that `s` corresponds to the `object sender` parameter, while `e` corresponds to the `DoWorkEventargs e` parameter. Of course, you don't have to name them `s` and `e`

Answer (score 1):

`_backgroundVideoWorker.DoWork` is an event that needs handlers.

`+=` indicates we are adding an event handler to handle the event.

`(s, e)` is saying that the expression is creating a function which accepts the `s` and `e` parameters required by the event for a function to handle it.  These represent an object (`s`) and the `DoWorkEventArgs` (`e`).   If you were to write a full function block instead of an inline lambda, they would look like `(object s, DoWorkEventArgs e)` or more familiarly `(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)`;